# Notepad++ how to replace end if line contains

Tags: notepad++

I really need your help!
This is my current situation:

If a line contains "Menu::choose"

```
Menu::choose("Invisible", invis);
Menu::choose("Never Wanted", neverw);
```

I need Notepad++ to replace the end " ); " with  " ,true); "
so it looks like this:

```
Menu::choose("Godmode", godmode, true);
Menu::choose("No Ragdoll", rag, true);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

On the Replace dialog, you need to make these entries:

- In the "Find what:" box you can enter:

  ```
    Menu::choose\((.*)\);
  ```
- In the "Replace with:" box you can enter:

  ```
    Menu::choose\(\1, true\);
  ```
- Then tick the "Regular Expression" bit at the bottom

Then when you hit "Replace All" it matches lines that match the "Find what:" regex and replaces it with the "Replace with:" thing (including that extra "true" parameter).

In a regex:

- the characters `(` and `)` are special so need to be escaped in a regex with `\(` and `\)`
- `(` and `)` denote a capture group that will assign whatever matches the inside to `\1`
- `.*` matches any number of characters.

So `Menu::choose\((.*)\);` will match:

- `Menu::choose(`
- any number of characters (assigned to `\1`)
- `);`

And `Menu::choose\(\1, true\);` replaces whatever is found with:

- `Menu::choose(`
- all those characters assigned to `\1`
- `, true);`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Menu::choose\([^)]+\K`
- Replace with: `, true`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
Menu::choose    # literally
\(              # open parenthese, have to be escaped as it has special meaning in regex
[^)]+           # negative character class, 1 or more NON close parenthesis
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]